# Vue.js table is rendered outside

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to render a table. The data is dynamic and comes from an array. It works fine, ***except:*** the table content is rendered outside of the table on top of the page.

I would like it to render inside the table. Would anyone be able to help?

This what the code looks like:

Vue.js:

```
Vue.component('word', {

    props: ['word-list'],

    template: '#word-template'


});

new Vue({
    el: '#root'

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="root">

    <word :word-list="{{json_encode($commonWords) }}"></word>

                <template id="word-template">

                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Key</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                            <tr v-for="(value, key) in wordList" :wordList="wordList">

                                <td> @{{ key }} </td>
                                <td> @{{ value }} </td>

                            </tr>

                        </tbody>

                    </table>

                </template>


</div>
```

**Note:** This is used with Laravel, thats why there is an @ before double curly braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the template for your component *inside* the template for your Vue. You need to move it *outside*.

```
<div id="root">
  <word :word-list="{{json_encode($commonWords) }}"></word>
</div>

<template id="word-template">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(value, key) in wordList" :wordList="wordList">
        <td> @{{ key }} </td>
        <td> @{{ value }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

If you leave the template for the component inside the template for the root, the root will compile the template for the component as part of it's own template.